# Custom Asp.Net CheckBox

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a custom checkbox (a regular checkbox but with one more property: a boolean LastValue) in Asp.Net C#, so I can know if the value was changed after a post back. What is the best approach you suggest?

Thank you!

Comment: Can do for querystring, persisting cookies or otherwise, depends on your need

Comment: Have you tried using `CheckedChanged`?

Comment: I would not advise creating a custom check box for your requirement. As 'PiLHA' commented, you can use query strings or hidden variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class that is derived from `CheckBox` and add a public property `LastValue` and be sure to save LastValue into the ViewState

From the default .ascx file, modified for class name and LastValue property

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string LastValue
        {
            get {
                object s = ViewState["LastValue"];
                return ( (s == null) ? "" : (string) ViewState["LastValue"] ) ;
            }
            set { ViewState["LastValue"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The @Page at the top of the default .ascx markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MyCheckBox" %>
```

A default aspx page with markup containing the user control.  After building the webApp the control is automatically place in a generic ToolBox, on my system the toolbox is called "WebApplication1 Components".  Dropping the control onto a default page created the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="WebApplication1" namespace="WebApplication1" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <cc1:MyCheckBox ID="MyCheckBox1" runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

One last thing: this is for simplicity.  If you'll notice on most, if not all, asp.net web controls there is the ability to disable the view state.  Most of the time it's left on, but the point is that it's up to the programmer.  ViewState to save a custom control property will work only so long as viewstate is enabled.  Disable it and say goodbye to LastValue.  A better (proper?) way would be to override the Save/LoadControlState() methods, but that's more involved so I'll leave it to you to determine how best to implement your requirements.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but if I make a class, how I add it to the designer?

Comment: create a user control (.ascx) and derive it from CheckBox rather than WebControl. compile and then just drop on page like any other control

Comment: Doesn't work. I also created a class derived (not a user control) from CheckBox, but I can't drag it like the user control.

Comment: if you create a user control, you'll notice the default inheritance is from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`, change it to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Checkbox` and add that public property and **compile** you should see the custom checkbox in the toolboc when you are viewing the page designer.

Comment: I did that but I am getting this error: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl). I deleted the code from the designer (<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>), but I can't drag and drop it into the page or see it into the toolbox. I also created a class which inherits CheckBox. This is what I want but I can't add it to the toolbox. So is just a part from what I am trying to create. Thank you for your post!

Comment: I don't know why you are having a problem - I'll append my answer above with sample code

Comment: Ok. Can't wait. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I am receiving this error: Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. I copied the code to posted, but unfortunately does not work. This error is shown when I am trying to access the page: Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Thank you!

Comment: The code was not meant to be dropped into your project verbatim, but to show you how to create a user control. Assuming that your project is a web application, create a user control and note the differences of my sample code to your newly created one.  Note what your project puts in place of where I have `WebApplication1`

Comment: Of course I did that. I made the changes to integrate it into my project. I will make a user control, drop a checkbox and make it public. And add to the user control the property. Is not what I wanted, but fits my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Aassuming you're working with HTML forms, you will want create a hidden field in the form with a similar name, populate it with your lastValue, and check the checkbox against that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkboxLastValue" value="true">
```

Comment: If I have a gridview with 1000 rows, I make a input for each one? Don't think so.